# How to override JavaScript Property

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

The following JavaScript is used globally e.g. it's automatically inserted in every web page in my web application:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#cemetracDataTable').dataTable( {
            "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
            "oTableTools": {
                "sSwfPath": "http://fubar.com/wp-content/TableTools-2.1.5/media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
                "aButtons": [
                    "copy",
                    "print",
                    {
                        "sExtends":    "collection",
                        "sButtonText": "Save",
                        "aButtons": [
                            {
                                "sExtends":     "csv",
                                "sButtonText":  "Excel (CSV)",
                                "bFooter":      false,
                                "sTitle":       "My title",
                                "sFileName":    "download.csv" // <-- override
                            },
                            {
                                "sExtends":     "xls",
                                "sButtonText":  "Excel (TSV)",
                                "bFooter":      false,
                                "sFileName":    "download.tsv" // <-- override
                            },
                            {
                                "sExtends":     "pdf",
                                "bFooter":      false,
                                "sFileName":    "download.pdf" // <-- override
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        } ).columnFilter();
    } );
</script>
```

I want to be able to overrride the sFileName properties on a certain web page e.g.:

```
...
"sFileName":    "widgets.csv"
...
"sFileName":    "widgets.tsv"
...
"sFileName":    "widgets.pdf"
```

Is doing so possible?  If so, how would this be done?

Comment: I'm not sure how you can get reference to passed object in `dataTable` method, so, would be better if you assign it to a variable and then pass that variable as argument to `dataTable` method. `$('#cemetracDataTable').dataTable(myObj)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would be better if you store object reference to a variable.

[***Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/de8Pr/)

```
var myObj = {
    sDom: 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
    oTableTools: {
        sSwfPath: "http://fubar.com/wp-content/TableTools-2.1.5/media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
        aButtons: [
            "copy",
            "print", {
                sExtends: "collection",
                sButtonText: "Save",
                aButtons: [ {
                        sExtends: "csv",
                        sButtonText: "Excel (CSV)",
                        bFooter: false,
                        sTitle: "My title",
                        sFileName: "download.csv" // <-- override
                    }, {
                        sExtends: "xls",
                        sButtonText: "Excel (TSV)",
                        bFooter: false,
                        sFileName: "download.tsv" // <-- override
                    }, {
                        sExtends: "pdf",
                        bFooter: false,
                        sFileName: "download.pdf" // <-- override
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

and then pass it as argument

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#cemetracDataTable').dataTable(myObj).columnFilter();
});
```

and if you want to change property `sFileName` values, you should refer them like this:

```
myObj.oTableTools.aButtons[2].aButtons[0].sFileName = "widgets.csv";
myObj.oTableTools.aButtons[2].aButtons[1].sFileName = "widgets.tsv";
myObj.oTableTools.aButtons[2].aButtons[2].sFileName = "widgets.pdf";
```

Comment: It worked.  It's WordPress so I had to put the object assignment `var myObj = ...` into the header, the object property overrides in the page itself and finally the method invocation in the footer.

Answer (score 2):

You can set javascript object properties using `.`:

Something along the lines of `aButtons[0].sFileName = "widgets.csv"` in your case.